# In BlueSky Statistics, how do I delete an analysis in the Output Window?

Tags: reporting

After exploring a few models, I generally want to delete those I don't need. How can I do that in BlueSky Statistics? Clicking on the section heading e.g. "Regression" doesn't select that section. I've tried right-clicking on that and choosing delete, but it just deletes the title, not the section.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, to actually delete an entire section of output, you have to do it one table at a time as you've discovered. That is, you right-click it and choose "Delete." The usual combinations of Shift-click and CTRL-click to choose many tables at once are not currently supported. The developers are aware of this problem and say it'll be fixed in a future release.

However, there is an alternative approach. In the Output Viewer, you can go to the Layout menu and choose "Show Navigation Tree", a series of check-boxes will appear by every piece of output. By un-checking a box, you can hide any table you don't want to see without having to delete it.